# Linux executable can't find shared library in same folder

Tags: c++, linux, bash, g++, shared-libraries

I am relatively new to Linux development, having been using Windows for a while now. Anyway, I am compiling a C++ game using g++ on both Windows and Linux (using mingw32 when needed), and am linking against SDL2 and SDL2_mixer. On Windows, one would only need to put the DLL files in the same folder as the executable and everything would run fine. On Linux however, although the code compiled just fine with not even a single warning, I get this at runtime :

```
./nKaruga: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

although said shared lib is in the same folder. I looked up several similar cases on Stack Overflow, all of them involving the use of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and tried it but to no avail.

```
% LD_LIBRARY_PATH=pwd
% export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
% ./nKaruga
./nKaruga: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I want to distribute this program on systems that do not necessarily have admin rights to install dependencies, hence why I am putting the SO in the same folder as the executable.

Thanks by advance !

Comment: `pwd` should be `\`pwd\``.

Comment: next time - "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" is your debugging line

Answer (score 20, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a quick ad-hoc hack to specify alternate library loading search paths. A more permanent and cleaner solution is to specify the specific sets of paths in which libraries shall be searched *specific* for your particular binary. This is called the *rpath* (Wikipedia article on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath). There are a number of "variables" that can be specified in the binary *rpath* that get substituted. In your case the rpath variable `${ORIGIN}` would be the most interesting for you. `${ORIGIN}` tells the dynamic linker to look for libraries within the very same directory in which also the binary resides.

The rpath can be set at link time with the `-rpath` linker option, i.e. when invoked through GCC the option would be `-Wl,-rpath='${ORIGIN}'`, i.e.

```
gcc -o program_binary -Wl,-rpath='${ORIGIN}' -lSDL2_mixer a.o b.o …
```

For an existing binary the rpath can be set post-hoc using the [`chrpath`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chrpath) or [`patchelf`](https://www.mankier.com/1/patchelf) tools; it's better to set it at link time proper, though.

Comment: This answer is helpful but does not address the question which is the title of the post, why can't the executable find the shared library when it is in the same location as the executable.

Comment: @shawn1874: The question of the OP didn't ask about the underlying reasons. The simple answer to the question "why" is: *Because the search order for shared objects on Linux is not the same as under Windows and by default does not include paths relative to the main executable. The `rpath` ELF header allows to augment the default shared object search behavior with custom paths, which may, or may not involve search locations relative to the main executable, by making use of the `${ORIGIN}` text substitution performed by the dynamic linker.*