# Cmake: How to set rpath to ${ORIGIN} with cmake

Tags: cmake, escaping, rpath

According to this SO question, [Linux executable can't find shared library in same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978762/linux-executable-cant-find-shared-library-in-same-folder) passing `-Wl,-rpath,${ORIGIN}` is the way to get a Linux executable to search for `.so`s in the same directory as the executable.

We're using cmake, so I'm adding a line of the form

```
target_link_options(Executable PRIVATE -Wl,-rpath=${ORIGIN})
```

to CMakeLists.txt.  The problem with that is that cmake tries to interpret the nine character sequence `${ORIGIN}` as a variable, and replaces it with nothing.

So far, I've tried:

```
$${ORIGIN}
\${ORIGIN}
$\{ORIGIN\}
$$\{ORIGIN\}
\$\{ORIGIN\}
```

none of which have worked.  How can I get this done?

-- Edit --

As noted by @Tsyvarev's comment, it turns out this was an XY problem in my particular case, since cmake has facilities directly designed to manipulate rpath.  Using this, I was able to get a solution.

In my case, adding the following three lines to CMakeLists.txt did the trick.

```
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$\{ORIGIN\}")
```

Note that part of our build process involves copying the `.so` to the output folder in preparation for building the final tarball artifact.  So using `-rpath=${ORIGIN}` works for both testing in the build tree, and final installation of the executable in the Docker container.

Comment: CMake has special ways for specify RPATH.  See [CMake RPATH handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) wiki and [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428219/cmake-rpath-origin-and-loader-path).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the information, looks like I was trying to solve an XY problem.  I've editied the question to be more specific about what I was asking, if you enter your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already noticed, you should use `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` or `INSTALL_RPATH`.
`INSTALL_RPATH` sets the `rpath` when installing a specific target.
`CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` is the global variant, doing the same for all targets.

I also struggled, how to escape `$ORIGIN`.
But, for me it works without escaping it at all:

```
set_target_properties(<target> PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")
```

Comment: Should damn well work, because `$ORIGIN` isn't how CMake expects a variable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It takes more than just setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` for me (cmake version 3.20.2, 3.7.2):

I've set `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` in a top level CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${LIB_INSTALL_PATH}:$ORIGIN")
```

This example also adds another path from a variable I created `LIB_INSTALL_PATH`.

For the target's CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
 set_target_properties(mytarget
   PROPERTIES
      BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH true
      LINK_OPTIONS "-Wl,--disable-new-dtags"
)
```

The `--disable-new-dtags` was need to use `RPATH` instead of `RUNPATH` (the new default) which apparently has issues.

Not adding anything to the target CMakeLists.txt file results in RPATH set to the build path:

```
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/home/brookbot/workspace/my_project/build/tgt/stuff:/home/brookbot/workspace/my_project/build/tgt]
```

But adding the property `BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH true` to the target gives me the desired result:

```
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/my/install/path:$ORIGIN]
```

I'm using `readelf -d` to examine the results.

I've also verified this works for cmake version 3.7.2 with the caveat that it generates a `RUNPATH` instead of `RPATH` (like the `LINK_OPTIONS` property does not work), but it still runs ok for me on target:

```
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/my/install/path:$ORIGIN]
```