# How to set rpath origin in cmake?

Tags: cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I found [Cmake: How to set rpath to ${ORIGIN} with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915564/cmake-how-to-set-rpath-to-origin-with-cmake) but my cmake does not have target_link_options.

I'm not installing the binary, I'm only "installing" it with `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, so I don't think `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` will work. Even though, I tried `SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$\{ORIGIN\}")` as suggested in the question, but I got

```
  Syntax error in cmake code at

  .../CMakeLists.txt:25

  when parsing string

    $\{ORIGIN\}

  Invalid escape sequence \{
```

I need to set this rpath which I was using in Makefile:

```
-rpath=\$$ORIGIN/lib
```

How to do it in cmake?

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following works for me on 3.14

```
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN)
```

This is what Craig Scott recommended in his  CppCon 2019 talk [Deep CMake for Library Authors](https://crascit.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Deep-CMake-For-Library-Authors-Craig-Scott-CppCon-2019.pdf) (Slide 100/110)

Comment: As per the slides, it's important to add that line before the add_executable

Comment: Note that this works on `make install`, not `make`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape $ sign not the brackets please see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

This works for me:

```
SET(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "\${ORIGIN}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH will set the value to all targets. To set for a single target, use `set_target_properties(<target> PROPERTIES INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")`. Original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75790542/1738637